# WPF Richtextbox Write to .txt file

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

```
    string okunanmetin;
    string Progfilepath;
    private void btnSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        richtextboxEdit.Document.Blocks.Remove(richtextboxEdit.Document.Blocks.ElementAt(0));
        Progfilepath = "C:/Users/SC/Desktop/test.txt";
        
        okunanmetin = File.ReadAllText(Progfilepath);
        richtextboxEdit.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(okunanmetin)));

    }
```

As you can see, I can insert a .txt file into the richtextbox. I am making changes in this text that I added. After this change I want to save to the same file.

I tried to do as seen below.

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadXamlPackage( "C:/Users/SC/Desktop/test.txt");
    }
    
    void LoadXamlPackage(string _fileName)
    {
        TextRange range;
        FileStream fStream;
        if (File.Exists(_fileName))
        {
            range = new TextRange(richtextboxEdit.Document.ContentStart, richtextboxEdit.Document.ContentEnd);
            fStream = new FileStream(_fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            range.Save(fStream, DataFormats.Text);
            fStream.Close();
        }
    }
```

It didn't work the way I wanted.

When I click the save button, it saves the changes but not everything.

Thanks for Support

Comment: The SO concept would suggest to post code as (formatted) text rather than images for web-search-ability. If you edit the question you can start with a new line containing just three back-ticks ``` - then paste your code - then add another ``` line at the bottom. Nice profile picture by the way

Comment: And perhaps you could describe what content was getting saved successfully as opposed what failed

Comment: @StefanWuebbe I did as you said. Can you vote on my question? I need someone's help.

Comment: @SamedÇETİN: What is means **_It didn't work the way I wanted._**? Describe in more details? Do you want to save all content of the `RichTextBox` as text, without formatting?

Comment: @Victor I worked so hard to reach you. But I didn't. You deleted your answered my last question. I m sorry.  Is there a way I can reach you?

Comment: @SamedÇETİN: **1)** See [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You asking a question - people answer the question. This how it works. **2)** I usually delete my answers that don't help.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys I solved the problems like the below.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (File.Exists(Progfilepath))
  {
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(richtextboxEdit.Document.ContentStart, richtextboxEdit.Document.ContentEnd);
    File.WriteAllText(Progfilepath, textRange.Text);
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually your code from the question should work too.  Why you are checking `if (File.Exists(Progfilepath))` if the file exists or not? If the file does not exists it will be created automatically by the ` File.WriteAllText()` method.

Comment: @Victor I've changed the question to make it clear. Actually the file path comes from somewhere else. I'm looking for a WPF related mentor. Can you help me ? Is there any way I can reach you?

Comment: See [Stack Overflow is a question and answer site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You asking a question - people answer the question. This how it works.